# How to use Facebook widgets in Ionic app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, facebook-like

I have integrated [ezfb](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb) in my Ionic app.

If I insert a Like Button (like in the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1c5cWB?p=preview)) , the button shows up when I debug in the desktop browser, but when I build an iOS app and test in the iOS simulator, the button is not shown.

```
   <div ng-show="data.post.meta.showfbwidgets" class="fb-like padding" onrender="widget.rendered = true" data-href="{{ data.post.link}}" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

How can I use Facebook widgets in an Ionic app?